# Accept list of ints in Flask url instead of one int

Tags: python, flask

My API has a route to process a user by an int id passed in the url.  I'd like to pass a list of ids so I can make one bulk request to the API rather than several single requests.  How can I accept a list of ids?

```
@app.route('/user/<int:user_id>')  # should accept multiple ints
def process_user(user_id):
    return str(user_id)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than passing it in the url, pass a form value.  Use `request.form.getlist` to get a list of values for a key, rather than a single value.  You can pass `type=int` to make sure all the values are ints.

```
@app.route('/users/', methods=['POST'])
def get_users():
    ids = request.form.getlist('user_ids', type=int)
    users = []

    for id in ids:
        try:
            user = whatever_user_method(id)
            users.append(user)
        except:
            continue

    returns users
```

Answer (score 7):

Write a [custom url converter](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/routing/#custom-converters) that accepts a list of ints separated by a delimiter, rather than just one int.  The [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors), for example, accepts multiple ids delimted by semicolons: `/answers/1;2;3`.  Register the converter with your app and use it in your route.

```
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class IntListConverter(BaseConverter):
    """Match ints separated with ';'."""

    # at least one int, separated by ;, with optional trailing ;
    regex = r'\d+(?:;\d+)*;?'

    # this is used to parse the url and pass the list to the view function
    def to_python(self, value):
        return [int(x) for x in value.split(';')]

    # this is used when building a url with url_for
    def to_url(self, value):
        return ';'.join(str(x) for x in value)

# register the converter when creating the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['int_list'] = IntListConverter

# use the converter in the route
@app.route('/user/<int_list:ids>')
def process_user(ids):
    for id in ids:
    ...

# will recognize /user/1;2;3 and pass ids=[1, 2, 3]
# will 404 on /user/1;2;z
# url_for('process_user', ids=[1, 2, 3]) produces /user/1;2;3
```

Answer (score 5):

*Simple as this*

```
@app.route('/user/<users>')
def process_user(users):
    users = list(users.split(","))
    print(users)
```

*Input*

```
/users/[1,2,3,4]
```

*Output*

```
[1,2,3,4]
```