# Capture a list of integers with a Flask route

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to implement a basic calculator in Flask.  I define two url parameters, which is manageable when I only want to add two values.  However, I want to add any number of values.  How can I get a list of integers without writing an infinitely long route?

```
@app.route('/add/<int:n1>,<int:n2>')
def add(n1,n2):
    sum = n1+n2
    return "%d" % (sum)
```

---

I tried to solve my problem with this code, but it's not working

```
integer_list = [] 
@app.route('/add/integer_list') 
def fun (integer_list):
    sum = 0
    for item in integer_list:
        sum = sum + item
    return '%d' % sum
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accept list of ints in Flask url instead of one int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237538/accept-list-of-ints-in-flask-url-instead-of-one-int)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a [custom url converter](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/#custom-converters) that matches comma separated digits, splits the matched string into a list of ints, and passes that list to the view function.

```
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class IntListConverter(BaseConverter):
    regex = r'\d+(?:,\d+)*,?'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return [int(x) for x in value.split(',')]

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ','.join(str(x) for x in value)
```

Register the converter on `app.url_map.converters`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['int_list'] = IntListConverter
```

Use the converter in the route.  `values` will be a list of ints.

```
@app.route('/add/<int_list:values>')
def add(values):
    return str(sum(values))
```

```
/add/1,2,3 -> values=[1, 2, 3]
/add/1,2,z -> 404 error
url_for('add', values=[1, 2, 3]) -> /add/1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? We just take the list of integers as a variable and then add them up.

```
import re

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/add/<int_list>')
def index(int_list):
    # Make sure it is a list that only contains integers.
    if not re.match(r'^\d+(?:,\d+)*,?$', int_list):
        return "Please input a list of integers, split with ','"
    result = sum(int(i) for i in int_list.split(','))
    return "{0}".format(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```