# How to properly render array parameter with swagger and flask restplus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I am implementing a Flask Application with Flask RestPlus that must receive a list of ids (integers) on a HTTP GET endpoint, so the application client can get a list of results matching those identifiers, for instance, with...

```
GET /resource/1,2,3,4
GET /resource?id=1,2,3
GET /resource?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

... which is not supported by default by [none of werkzeug bultin converters](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/routing/#builtin-converters), but following the steps in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437908/7372188) the url parsing is working properly and I can receive the list of ids with this converter...

```
class ListOfIntegerConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, randomify=False):
        self.regex = r'\d+(?:,\d+)*,?'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return [int(x) for x in value.split(',')]

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ','.join(str(x) for x in value)
```

... which is then properly registered [as stated here](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#custom-converters) ...

`app.url_map.converters['list_of_int'] = ListOfIntegerConverter`

... and used to parse the url parameters ...

```
@my_namespace.route('/<list_of_int:list_of_ids>/', methods=["GET"])
class MyResourceById(Resource):
    def get(self, list_of_ids):
        [print(id, type(id)) for id in list_of_ids]
```

... but the generated swagger documentation is rendering the field as a plain string instead of an array or list of integers, which should be rendered like this...

[image: swagger list of integers]

I know that swagger supports [multi-value parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/#array-and-multi-value-parameters), but I can't manage to make Flask RestPlus render this field accordingly. Is there anyone who knows how to do it that can help me out with some advice?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use [arg parsers](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html):

```
id_parser = api.parser()
id_parser.add_argument('id[]', type=int, action='append')

@api.route('/ids', methods=["GET"])
@api.doc(parser=id_parser)
class MyResourceById(Resource):

    @staticmethod
    def get():
        ids = request.args.getlist('id[]')
        print(ids)
        return ids
```

I'd do it as above, but you can probably get it working with your converter too.

The documents say parser is being deprecated but not anytime soon, and I couldn't personally find an alternative.

Comment: You seem to be a new contributor, welcome, and thanks, your answer is correct and made me notice one mistake on my code! It is fair that I do can parse the parameters but cannot see it as a list on swagger, since I'm only using the [api.marshal_with decorator](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/documenting.html#documenting-with-the-api-marshal-with-decorator), which documents the get method, but not the [api.doc decorator](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/documenting.html#documenting-with-the-api-doc-decorator), which documents the resource.

Comment: I'll upvote, it do solves the documentation problem, even though the flask restfull documentation says the parser is deprecated, but I'll still try to figure out how to use my custom parser to complement your solution, probably getting it from the [url_map](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.url_map).

Comment: I'll accept the answer, since I couldn't find a better solution that doesn't use the deprecated parser. Thanks again!